# MongoDB - Inserting the result of a query in one round-trip

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Consider this hypothetical snippet:

```
using (mongo.RequestStart(db))
{
    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");

    var insertDoc = new BsonDocument { { "currentCount", collection.Count() } };
    WriteConcernResult wcr = collection.Insert(insertDoc);
}
```

It inserts a new document with "currentCount" set to the value returned by collection.Count().

This implies two round-trips to the server. One to calculate collection.Count() and one to perform the insert. Is there a way to do this in one round-trip?

In other words, can the value assigned to "currentCount" be calculated on the server at the time of the insert?

Thanks!

Comment: It's only 1 call instead of 2. That isn't a big difference. I don't think you can do that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this currently (Mongo 2.4).

The upcoming 2.6 version should have batch operations support but I don't know if it will support batching operations of different types and using the results of one operation from another operation.

What you can do, however, is execute this logic on the server by expressing it in JavaScript and using [eval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/):

```
collection.Database.Eval(new BsonJavaScript(@"
  var count = db.test.count();
  db.test.insert({ currentCount: count });
");
```

But this is not recommended, because of several reasons: you lose the write concern, it is very unsafe in terms of security, it requires admin permissions, it holds a global write lock, and it won't work on sharded clusters :)

I think your best route at the moment would be to do this in two queries. 
If you're looking for atomic updates or counters (which don't exactly match your example but seem somewhat related), take a look at [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) and the [$inc operator of update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will avoid the javascript route as you suggest. I definitely don't want to give up the write concern. I was originally wondering if javascript could be used just for calculating the count (i.e., somehow pass an eval expression as the value of the field) and insert like in the original code, but alas this kind of thing is probably not supported nor wise.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a large collection and you're looking to save CPU, it's recommended that you create another collection called `counters` that only has one document per collection that you want to count and increment the document pertaining to you're collection each time you insert a document.

[See the guidance here.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

It appears that you can place a JavaScript function inside your query, so perhaps it can be done in one trip, but I haven't implemented this in my own app, so I can't confirm that.